# Documentation on using CiviCase tokens

Tags: civicase, tokens, duplicate-contacts

Civicase Tokens Extension does not have documentation.   I am trying to use the tokens to do a print/merge of case information.  The print page is blank.

Any suggestions?   Have case tokens been used in this way?

[image: Print?Merge using Case tokens]

Comment: This should work. It works for me.
Are you able to print/merge normally, from other pages?
Have you tried defining a Page Format?

Comment: Thanks, I have it working now.   Only thing different is that I deleted my test case and started over with new cases and it works now.   The prior case I was testing with had been created before I updated Civi.  Possibly related or possibly something else going on.   (When it wasn't working I had the same type problem exporting case data and the custom data fields were blank in that as well.)   On we go ...